# How to provide bloc to replaced widget through pushReplacement?

Tags: flutter, flutter-navigation, flutter-bloc

I have a parent stless widget like so,

```dart
class LoginScreen extends StatelessWidget {
    
   final AuthRepository authRepository = AuthRepository(AuthApiClient());
    
   @override
   Widget build(BuildContext context) {
      return BlocProvider(
          create: (BuildContext context) {
            return LoginBloc(Idle(), authRepository);
          },
          child: LoginWithEmailIdScreen(),
      );
   }
}
```

I'm able to access the bloc in `LoginWithEmailIdScreen` just fine, but when I replace`LoginWithEmailIdScreen` with another screen (`LoginWithMobileNumberScreen`) as so, the bloc instance seems to be null.
*Inside LoginWithEmailIdScreen :*

```
Navigator.pushReplacement(
   context,
   MaterialPageRoute(
      builder: (_) => BlocProvider.value(
         value: BlocProvider.of<LoginBloc>(context),
         child: LoginWithMobileNumberScreen(),
      )
   )
);
```

Thought it was the wrong context being used, so replaced it with `_` but still the same issue.

How to provide the bloc instance?

Any help is appreciated as I'm very new to flutter. Thanks.

Comment: @Uni thanks for the quick response. Switching to rxdart is probably out of the question haha as it's not my own app for such a large refactor. I did encounter BlocListener, but it seemed super messy to have a state/bloc just for UI navigation. Will look into it tho, thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I couldn't find a good way to provide bloc through pushReplacement without using routes.

Had to refactor the whole project and implement routes to used named alternatives as so :

```
Navigator.of(context).pushNamedAndRemoveUntil(
                  Routes.LOGIN_WITH_MOBILE_SCREEN,
                  (Route<dynamic> route) => false);
```

and pass the bloc and manage in `onGenerateRoute`.